# R, find average length of consecutive time-steps in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, group

I have the following `data.frame` with `time` column sorted in ascending order:

```
colA=c(1,2,5,6,7,10,13,16,19,20,25,40,43,44,50,51,52,53,68,69,77,79,81,82)
colB=rnorm(24)

df=data.frame(time=colA, x=colB)
```

How can I count and take the average of the consecutive time-steps observed in the `time` column?

In detail, I need to group the rows in the `time` column by consecutive observations, e.g. 1,2 and 5,6,7 and 19,20 and 43,44, etc... and then take the average of the length of each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group clusters of consecutive observations like this:

```r
df$group <- c(0, cumsum(diff(df$time) != 1)) + 1
```

Which gives:

```r
df
#>    time          x group
#> 1     1  0.7443742     1
#> 2     2  0.1289818     1
#> 3     5  1.4882743     2
#> 4     6 -0.6626820     2
#> 5     7 -1.1606550     2
#> 6    10  0.3587742     3
#> 7    13 -0.1948464     4
#> 8    16 -0.2952820     5
#> 9    19  0.4966404     6
#> 10   20  0.4849128     6
#> 11   25  0.0187845     7
#> 12   40  0.6347746     8
#> 13   43  0.7544441     9
#> 14   44  0.8335890     9
#> 15   50  0.9657613    10
#> 16   51  1.2938800    10
#> 17   52 -0.1365510    10
#> 18   53 -0.4401387    10
#> 19   68 -1.2272839    11
#> 20   69 -0.2376531    11
#> 21   77 -0.9268582    12
#> 22   79  0.4112354    13
#> 23   81 -0.1988646    14
#> 24   82 -0.5574496    14
```

You can get the length of these groups by doing:

```r
rle(df$group)$lengths
#> [1] 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 4 2 1 1 2
```

And the *average* length of the consecutive groups is:

```r
mean(rle(df$group)$lengths)
#> [1] 1.714286
```

And the average of x within each group using

```r
tapply(df$x, df$group, mean)
#>          1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
#>  0.4366780 -0.1116876  0.3587742 -0.1948464 -0.2952820  0.4907766  0.0187845 
#>          8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
#>  0.6347746  0.7940166  0.4207379 -0.7324685 -0.9268582  0.4112354 -0.3781571
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, doing some kind of consecutive length encoding:

```r
l = diff(c(0, which(diff(df$time) != 1), nrow(df)))
l
# [1] 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 4 2 1 1 2

mean(l)
#[1] 1.714286
```